# How to assign AJAX response to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save/assign an AJAX success response to a global variable. The response is fetched into a `<p>` tag, but how can I assign this response into a global variable for further use?

```
var x;

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: {
    sending data
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.d)
  }
});
```

Comment: It's just `x = data.d` however you now have the problem of knowing when this executes. As such you really should not be doing it in this way, not least because global variables are a code smell. A far better approach is to use promises/callbacks properly instead of globals.

Comment: I am not able to get your question but could you use .always  in your ajax is it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assign the data.d to x in the success block. The final solution would be

```
var x;

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: {
    sending data
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    x = data.d;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
const ajaxData = $.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    global: false,
    type: "POST",

    dataType: "jsonData",
    async:false,
    success: function(msg){
     return msg;
   }
 }).responseText;
console.log(JSON.parse(ajaxData));
</script>
```